# How to make a generic quicksort method run correctly with objects in an arraylist

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to finish a program that uses a generic quicksort method to sort an arraylist of objects, I finally got rid of all the common errors I was familiar with but my program is still not sorting properly. I used a similar algorithm when I was sorting just Strings and it was not generic so I'm not sure where I went wrong. Please help! 
Here is the following quicksort code I have been working with:

```
private static <E> void doQuickSort(ArrayList <E> list, int start, int end)
{
    if(list == null || list.size() == 0)
        return;
    if(start >= end)
        return;

    int middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
    E pivot = (E) list.get(middle);

    int s = start, e = end;
    while (s <= e)
    {
        while(pivot.equals(list.get(s)))
        {
            s++;
        }

        while(pivot.equals(list.get(e)))
            e--;


    if(s <= e)
    {
        E temp = list.get(s);
        list.set(s,  list.get(e));
        list.set(e, temp);
        s++;
        e--;
    }


    if(start < e)
        doQuickSort(list, start, e);
    if(end > s)
        doQuickSort(list, s, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: How will this work if E does not extend Comparable?

Comment: I actually have not used extends Comparable, my previous program did not need it when using compareTo() with my Strings, and my research said the equals() method would work for objects. Is there no other way in this situation? p.s. I am very new to this so sorry if that sounds odd!

Comment: How the hell will `equals(...)` determine a sort? You need to know if something is greater than or less than, something that equals will never give you.

Comment: You are not sorting anything.  Sorting requires some concept of "less than" or "greater than" _in addition to_ "equals", because "less than" is the same as "must appear before".  This is what `Comparable` is for.  You never compare any items (`compareTo` does not appear in your program), therefore whatever you are doing is not "sorting" in any usual sense of the word.

Comment: @A.Linden `equals` returns true or false while compare returns 3 values - less then, greater then, equal.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are Comparable so you can use compareTo with a String.  When you made it generic, you did not specify that the generic elements have to be Comparable, and from your code you are no longer using compareTo.  If you use equals instead of compareTo, you cannot determine which elements come before which other elements.  As a result, you are not sorting anything.